# How can I use the event overlayadd layers in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, leaflet, dom-events

I have problem in leaflet events.
I want use this event: [link]https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-overlayadd this event over lay add (Fired when an overlay is selected through the layer control).

I want when  selected any layers through the layer control save layer name in var Name. How can I this?
I have 3 layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work for me.
Thanks from Falke Design.

For baselayer:

```js
var SelectedLayer='OSM';  // default value 
map.on('baselayerchange', function(eo) {
  if (eo.name === 'ge3') {
    SelectedLayer='ge3';}
  if (eo.name === 'ge2') {
    SelectedLayer='ge2';

  } else if (eo.name !== 'ge2' && eo.name !== 'ge3' ) {
    SelectedLayer=eo.name;
  }
  console.log('SelectedLayer>>>>>>>>>>>>>>',SelectedLayer);
});
```

For overlayers:

```
var name;
map.on('overlayadd', function(e){
   name = e.name;
   console.log(name);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var name;
map.on('overlayadd', function(e){
   name = e.name;
   console.log(name);
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.